# ALTER TABLE SQL Oracle - 12c

Tags: sql, database, oracle

we are confused with below answers.so our answer is 3, 5

Which three actions can you perform by using the ALTER TABLE command?

1- Lock a set of rows in a table.

2- Drop pseudocolumns from a table.

3- Rename a table.

4- Drop all columns simultaneously from a table.

5- Enable or disable constraints on a table.

6- Restrict all DML statements on a table.

Thank you

Comment: What are pseudo columns? Virtual columns, maybe? Then yes, you can drop them just like any other column with `ALTER TABLE`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner [`ROWNUM` is a pseudocolumn](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3, 5 and 6

---

1. Lock a set of rows in a table.

   Oracle locks rows it is performing DML on or when you use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`; you cannot lock rows with `ALTER TABLE`.
2. Drop pseudocolumns from a table.

   The common [pseudocolumns](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/pseudocolumns.htm#SQLRF0025) of a table are `ROWID`, `ROWNUM` and `ORA_ROWSCN`; you cannot drop these.
3. Rename a table.

   ```sql
   CREATE TABLE table_name ( a NUMBER, b NUMBER );
   ALTER TABLE table_name RENAME TO other_name;
   ```

   Works.
4. Drop all columns simultaneously from a table.

   ```sql
   CREATE TABLE table_name ( a NUMBER, b NUMBER );
   ALTER TABLE table_name DROP ( a, b );
   ```

   Outputs:

   ```
   ORA-12983: cannot drop all columns in a table
   ```
5. Enable or disable constraints on a table.

   ```sql
   CREATE TABLE table_name ( a NUMBER CONSTRAINT qu5__pk PRIMARY KEY, b NUMBER );
   ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY PRIMARY KEY DISABLE;
   ```

   Will disable the constraint.
6. Restrict all DML statements on a table.

   ```sql
   CREATE TABLE table_name ( a NUMBER, b NUMBER );
   ALTER TABLE table_name READ ONLY;
   ```

   Then

   ```sql
   INSERT INTO table_name ( a, b ) VALUES ( 1, 1 );
   UPDATE table_name SET b = 2;
   DELETE FROM table_name;
   ```

   all fail with the exception:

   ```
   ORA-12081: update operation not allowed on table "SCHEMA_NAME"."TABLE_NAME"
   ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=898eb68bbbd38007c522727913d0aa46)*